# Update App state based on Child component

Tags: reactjs, async-await, parent-child, react-props

I need to update the state of a Parent component (**App.js**) when updating the state of a `Child` component where I do a `GET` request in `componentDidMount()`.

I tried to pass the function `setPoints` as a prop but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Here's what I tried :

`Child` component :

```
class Child extends Component {

    state = {
        points: null
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url);
            const data = res.data;
            this.setState({
                points: data.points,
            })
            this.props.setPoints();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('child', err);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Parent component (`App`):

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        points: '',
    }

    setPoints() {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            points: this.state.points
        });
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextState) {
        if (this.state.points !== nextState.points) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Route exact path="/child" render={() => <Child setPoints={this.setPoints} />} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried what Joe Clay wrote and this makes perfect sense, but I still catch an error. Here's my updated code :

```
    async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        const data = res.data;
        console.log(data.points);
        this.props.setPoints(data.points);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('child', err);
    }
```

It does log the value of points, but for some reason I get : "Cannot read property 'points' of undefined".

Comment: Please read [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) on the React docs site. Storing the same piece of state in two separate components is almost always an indication that you're going about things the wrong way - idiomatic React code usually has a 'single source of truth' for any given piece of data.

Comment: Also please read about setting state computed based on current state using updater function https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the value of data in Parent Component.I would be changing the value of data by passing a prop to a function which does a setState in the parent and thereby changing the value to the desired value.

ParentComponent

```
class Parent extends React.Component{    
    constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state({
             name:''
         })
    }    

     handleChange(value){
         this.setState({name:value});
     }
     render(){
         return (<Child handleChange={this.handleChange} />)
     }
}
```

Pass the handleChange function as a prop to the child component.

Child component

```
export default class Child extends React.Component{
     sendData(false){
        this.props.handleChange(hello)   //make sure to pass the value in the 
          argument that you wish to do a setState on in the parent component
     }   
}
```

this would set the value of name to hello in the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

on child:

```
this.props.setPoints(data.points)
```

on parent:

```
setPoints(points) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        points
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly this and this makes sense, unfortunately the request catches this error : "Cannot read property 'points' of undefined".

Comment: console.log(res.data) and check result is ok

Comment: The log does work, so I can't figure out why I get this error

Comment: it says data is undefined. can you send console log of axios result here?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used Ercik's solution instead and it works great. I still don't know what was wrong with the argument in setPoints though...